# Query importrange within date parameters and separate time parameters returning percentage

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I have created this formula that should count all rows from another sheet with the specific mentioned value with date range => & =< and with time range => & =<

It returns 0 regardless of what values I test with...

```
    =COUNTA(IFERROR(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("/1xNFVHLnQGkRgZdLmejCyU0BByOPBY8NMoIYj6SkTFGY/edit#gid=431567503", "July!A2:C")}, 
                       "Select Col1 where Col1 contains '"&A3&"' 
                                      and Col2 >= date '2022-07-01' 
                                      and Col2 <= date '2022-07-31'
                                      and Col3 >= time '18:00'
                                      and Col3 <= time '08:00'" ,0)))
```

Data:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xNFVHLnQGkRgZdLmejCyU0BByOPBY8NMoIYj6SkTFGY/edit#gid=431567503

Testing sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xNFVHLnQGkRgZdLmejCyU0BByOPBY8NMoIYj6SkTFGY/edit#gid=1075801741

In the ideal world I would want to take this a step further and instead of a count of this data it would return a percentage of all the data based on the partner name in Sheet2! '"&A3&"'

Update
1 step closer:
=COUNTA(IFERROR(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("/1xNFVHLnQGkRgZdLmejCyU0BByOPBY8NMoIYj6SkTFGY/edit#gid=431567503", "July!A2:D")},
"Select Col1 where Col1 contains '"&A3&"'
and Col4 >= datetime '"&TEXT(H1,"e-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")&"'
and Col4 <= datetime '"&TEXT(H2,"e-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")&"'",0)))

This formula returns data that is within a specific time and date range and has a particular value in a column.

The way I worded the original question would mean I am now almost there.

Answer (score 1):

there is no `time`. go for `datetime`:

[image]

---

### update:

D2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,B2:B+C2:C))
```

G4:

```
=COUNTA(IFERROR(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE(
 "1WsQQJ3qWM_m-nHW6R4xhewgQTfN5haZ61eJx1KkgaSg", "July!A2:D")}, 
 "select Col1 
  where Col4 >= datetime '"&TEXT(H1, "e-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")&"'
    and Col4 <= datetime '"&TEXT(H2, "e-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")&"'", 0)))
```

[image]

### [demo sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WsQQJ3qWM_m-nHW6R4xhewgQTfN5haZ61eJx1KkgaSg/edit#gid=431567503)

Comment: Thank you. So in the case of my example, I would need to concat the date and time columns I guess. I also realised a massive flaw in my original question as the time parameter within the required date range spans 2 days for each time range. Eg. 18:00 on 2022-05-01 to 08:00 on 2022-05-01 and 18:00 on 2022-05-02 to 08:00 on 2022-05-03 and 18:00 on 2022-05-03 to 08:00 on 2022-05-04 etc.

Comment: @Stuart yes thats on of the posibilities

Comment: I can’t seem to get this to work even with just 1 datetime from either the combined datetime or separate date time columns

Comment: @Stuart answer updated

Comment: @Stuart you forgot `and` ... `=COUNTA(IFERROR(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1xNFVHLnQGkRgZdLmejCyU0BByOPBY8NMoIYj6SkTFGY/edit", "July!A2:D")}, "select Col1 where Col1 contains '"&A2&"' and Col4 >= datetime '"&TEXT(H1, "e-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")&"' and Col4 <= datetime '"&TEXT(H2, "e-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")&"'", 0)))`

Comment: Thanks again, I've replicated your queries which work to the defined datetime range.
In Sheet2! g7 I tried to add where Col1 contains '"&A2&"'

=COUNTA(IFERROR(QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("/1xNFVHLnQGkRgZdLmejCyU0BByOPBY8NMoIYj6SkTFGY/edit#gid=431567503", "July!A2:D")},  "select Col1 where Col1 contains '"&A2&"'
Col4 >= datetime '"&TEXT(H1, "e-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")&"'
  and Col4 <= datetime '"&TEXT(H2, "e-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")&"'", 0)))

This returns 0.

I will also need to 'and Col4 <= datetime' for every day of the month to cover the correct datetime ranges before 08:00 but after 18:00 each day

Comment: Thanks, my many miss-types but still doesn't seem to work